# Android - Changing screen orientation

Tags: android

Suppose that within an activity my initial screen orientation is landscape. In the same activity, I would like to add a button which changes the screen orientation from landscape to portrait.

Is this possible in any way, or should I switch to a new activity ?

Thanks.

Comment: Initially in my activity a, the screen orientation is fixed to landscape as described in android manifest file, this works as intended for many layouts, but on the last layout - I know where I call it - I would like to change that line in manifest file from landscape to portrait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add new views to your layout, but first you need to detect the orientation change which is explained in the following link how it's done.

[How to detect orientation change in layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android)

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use Activity.setRequestedOrientation() method