# How to handle orientation change easily

Tags: android, orientation-changes

I'm working on a android application that adds every view programmaticaly.
When the user turns the screen, I just want to values that are filled in to be displayed again.
Is there an easy way to let Android do this automaticaly?

My application is completely dynamic so it doens't have a predetermined layout, which makes it a lot harder.

So, how can I easily save the state of my screen?

Comment: Why don't you fix the orientation?

Comment: Normally widgets like EditBoxes etc do save their state including values on orientation change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everytime orientation change, android create new view and destroy the old one. You can saved your data when orientation change and re-initialize when the new view is created

Use `onConfigurationChanged` method of activity to detect Orientation Change

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
```

Don't forget to edit the appropriate element in your AndroidManifest.XML like this to include the `android:configChanges`

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

For an expanded explanation of Hein's correct answer see my previous post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57239493/5696328