# Android detect orientation change from portrait to landscape, vice versa

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-orientation

I need to detect before the orientation changes so that i know if it is orientation change i don't have to add a score to database inside a fragment. Is it possible to do that? `OrientationChangeListener` and `configuration change` didn't work for me, as i understand config updates after the fact and orientation listener at every degree the device is moved.

Comment: This is not great practice, but you can try overriding `onConfigurationChanged`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5726776/379245

Comment: thanks, but does it call the method prior to DESTROYING the fragment/activity, or after the fact? because i need it before it destroys it.

Comment: If you use that, your activity will not be destroyed and recreated. That's the downside. You will have to handle everything in the onConfigurationChanged function yourself.

Comment: The activity *is* destroyed *after* the orientation change.  Therefore, onSaveInstanceSate() is called between orientation change and onDestroy().

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up, I will give it a try :)