# Android Orientation tag error

Tags: android

I am using eclipse android 
I want to know about the orientantion changes ,when orientation changes gget a log message in logid ,Below is our code

```
package com.example.orientation;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
 }
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Log.d("Android","orientation changes"+newConfig.orientation);
 }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.orientation"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.orientation.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

here we don't get the message in the log cat .I am trying to log the integer value of the orientation .there is no error in the code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect orientation change in layout in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android)

Comment: <activity
        android:name="com.example.orientation.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">

How this code can be compiled ! There's an xml error here..

Answer (score 0):

Use 
 `<activity
        android:name="com.example.orientation.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">`

Instead of this....
`<activity
        android:name="com.example.orientation.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">`

see the difference