# Rotate Layout both clockwise and anticlockwise based on the user interaction with the layout

Tags: android

Below code rotates clockwise when touched. What I want is to detect the user interaction with the layout and rotate accordingly.

```
relative.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                relative.animate().rotationBy(60).setDuration(300).start();
            }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                relative.animate().rotationBy(0).setDuration(10).start();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Without using animation stuff, using animations some functions like onClick events don't work properly on the layout.

Comment: Above description is not so helpful!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect orientation change in layout in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android).

Comment: it's not about orientation at all.....it's an image in a layout, a circular image which I am trying to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check about roation issues just go through [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html) and in [Sensor Events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

Comment: it's not about orientation , it's about rotation

Comment: thats not what i looking for, you've given about sensor of device rotation, I am talking about just a relative layout which rotates on onTouch event

Comment: so when it roatates as you mentioned you want to detect..so definately it is the issue related potrait and landscape..and what else you want to detect?

Comment: take a look at this page http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868, I implemented this to rotate but onClick events are not working. That's the reason why I am rotating a layout, so to work with OnClick events. I am able with clockwise rotation but couldn't with anticlickwise and clockwise both together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92357/discussion-between-lakhan-and-johnrao07).