# What is the Android equivalent of UIDeviceOrientation and UIInterfaceOrientation?

Tags: android, ios, orientation

On iOS, device orientation can be different from interface orientation, so we have two different enums. I'm not necessarily looking for enums. Does Android make the same distinction? I want to detect interface orientation changes rather than device.

People seem to be using [`onConfigurationChanged()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5726776/812582) to detect orientation changes, but it wasn't clear to me exactly what kind of orientation change this is.

Answer (score 0):

this methods can detect (and) set orientation:

`getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`
and
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

I'm using those methods to catch all orientations:

inside `onCreate`:

`initOrientation();`

where

```
private void initOrientation() {
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mLastRotation = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        myOrientationEventListener
        = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI){
         @Override
         public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
//         Log.d(TAG, "ORIENTATION: " + orientation);
         Display display = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
         int rotation = display.getRotation();
         if (((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 && mLastRotation == Surface.ROTATION_270)
                 || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270 && mLastRotation == Surface.ROTATION_90)
                 || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 && mLastRotation == Surface.ROTATION_180)
                 || (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180 && mLastRotation == Surface.ROTATION_0))) {
             //if ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) && rotation != mLastRotation) {
             Log.i(TAG, "changed >>> " + rotation + " :: " + _.mWidth);

             // do something

             mLastRotation = rotation;
         }
         }
         };

           if (myOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            myOrientationEventListener.enable();
           }
           else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't DetectOrientation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          //  finish();
           }
    }
```

it depends on what your really want to realize. the method above can detect portrait>portrait and landscape>landscape shifts.

In order to force lock and release rotation I'm using this approach:

```
protected void mLockScreenRotation(int i)
{
  // Stop the screen orientation changing during an event
    switch (i)
    {
    default:
    case 0:
        switch (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation)
        {
          case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
              this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
              break;
          case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
              this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
              break;
        }
    case 1:
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        break;
    case 2:
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        break;
    }
}
```

`mLockScreenRotation(0)` - locks

Comment: This is an interesting approach with the sensor manager. Do you get rotation updates if the screen is locked or your app is paused/backgrounded?

Comment: @Mark13426 , I do not say about the activity,I'm interesting too how it works in the backgroud.  but you can use this code inside a foreground service that should work.

Comment: @Mark13426 , I've edited my post and have written one more method.

Comment: It seems Android doc suggests SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL for orientation changes: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL. Have you tried it in your code?

Comment: @Mark13426 , this is just a precision for detection. You can use any value you want.