# Android. Remove inflated Fragment when screen orientation changes(Portrait <-> Landscape)?

Tags: android, android-fragments

MainActivity inflates a fragment like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.dashboard_fragment_container, df, TAG_DASHBOARD_FRAGMENT)
            .commit();
```

But when the screen orientation changes, I wish to remove(destroy) this fragment.

Any easy way to detect when the screen is about to change, so that I can remove inflated fragments?

Comment: I think this link might helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android.

Comment: What is the reason for removing the fragment?

Answer (score 3):

Try using method onConfigurationChanged(). It will detect screen orientation change.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //remove fragment
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Set these condition in onCreate(), because orientation change will call onCreate() method again:

```
if(Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.dashboard_fragment_container, df, TAG_DASHBOARD_FRAGMENT)
            .commit();
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

`Fragments` usually get recreated on `configuration` change. If you don't want this to happen, use

`setRetainInstance(true);` in the Fragment's constructor

This will cause fragments to be retained during configuration change.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean))

Now When the Activity is restarted because of a orientation change, the Android Framework recreates and adds the Fragment automatically.

if u want to remove fragment during [configuration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) change use:

In **Activity**

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Also in Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Now in onCreate() of Activity remove Fragment using:

```
    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);  //your fragment
if(f == null){
    //there is no Fragment
}else{
    //It's already there remove it
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```