# When I change the page orientation come at the beginning of page

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am using [barteksc-AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer). I am using this code

```
package com.github.barteksc.sample;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.listener.OnPageChangeListener;
import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.scroll.DefaultScrollHandle;
import com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfDocument;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.NonConfigurationInstance;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.OnActivityResult;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.OptionsItem;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.OptionsMenu;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

import java.util.List;

@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.options)
public class PDFViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, OnLoadCompleteListener {

    private static final String TAG = PDFViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int REQUEST_CODE = 42;
    public static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 42042;

    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "sample.pdf";
    public static final String READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";

    @ViewById
    PDFView pdfView;

    @NonConfigurationInstance
    Uri uri;

    @NonConfigurationInstance
    Integer pageNumber = 0;

    String pdfFileName;

    @OptionsItem(R.id.pickFile)
    void pickFile() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSION_CODE
            );

            return;
        }

        launchPicker();
    }

    void launchPicker() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            //alert user that file manager not working
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_pick_file_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @AfterViews
    void afterViews() {
        if (uri != null) {
            displayFromUri(uri);
        } else {
            displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
        }
        setTitle(pdfFileName);
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName) {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;

        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }

    private void displayFromUri(Uri uri) {
        pdfFileName = getFileName(uri);

        pdfView.fromUri(uri)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }

    @OnActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE)
    public void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            uri = intent.getData();
            displayFromUri(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", pdfFileName, page + 1, pageCount));
    }

    public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
        String result = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        Log.e(TAG, "title = " + meta.getTitle());
        Log.e(TAG, "author = " + meta.getAuthor());
        Log.e(TAG, "subject = " + meta.getSubject());
        Log.e(TAG, "keywords = " + meta.getKeywords());
        Log.e(TAG, "creator = " + meta.getCreator());
        Log.e(TAG, "producer = " + meta.getProducer());
        Log.e(TAG, "creationDate = " + meta.getCreationDate());
        Log.e(TAG, "modDate = " + meta.getModDate());

        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");

    }

    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep) {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree) {

            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));

            if (b.hasChildren()) {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Listener for response to user permission request
     *
     * @param requestCode  Check that permission request code matches
     * @param permissions  Permissions that requested
     * @param grantResults Whether permissions granted
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                launchPicker();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

to change the orientation of the page. But if I have to assume if the portrait mode and page number 15 in change page orientation of the page when we started the landscape.

[image]
[image]

Please help me about this.

Comment: Check this answer. Maybe it could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android

Comment: @Ahmer any news regarding this issue?

Comment: @Akis Still not, It can't implement I'm trying many times but fail to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_pdf_app_bar_main)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.options)
public class PDFActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnPageChangeListener, OnLoadCompleteListener
{
    private static final String TAG = PDFActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static int REQUEST_CODE = 42;
    public static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 42042;
    public static final String SAMPLE_FILE = "myPDF.pdf";
    public static final String READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
    private int mCurrentPage = 0;
    private final static String KEY_CURRENT_PAGE = "current_page";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @ViewById
    PDFView pdfView;
    @NonConfigurationInstance
    Uri uri;
    @NonConfigurationInstance
    String pdfFileName;
    @OptionsItem(R.id.pickFile)
    void pickFile()
    {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_CODE);
            return;
        }
        launchPicker();
    }
    void launchPicker()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        try
        {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_pick_file_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @AfterViews
    void afterViews()
    {
        pdfView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        if (uri != null)
        {
            displayFromUri(uri);
        }
        else
        {
            displayFromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE);
        }
        setTitle(pdfFileName);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void displayFromAsset(String assetFileName)
    {
        pdfFileName = assetFileName;
        pdfView.fromAsset(SAMPLE_FILE)
                .defaultPage(mCurrentPage)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .password(null)
                .enableAntialiasing(true)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onPageScroll(new OnPageScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int page, float positionOffset) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPageScrolled: page " + page + " positionOffset " + positionOffset);
                    }
                })
                .onRender(new OnRenderListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitiallyRendered(int nbPages, float pageWidth, float pageHeight)
                    {
                        pdfView.fitToWidth(mCurrentPage);
                    }
                })
                .onLoad(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void loadComplete(int nbPages) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "loadComplete: totalPages " + nbPages);
                    }
                })
                .onError(new OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        Log.d(TAG, " onError");
                    }
                })
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .spacing(2)
                .load();
    }
    private void displayFromUri(Uri uri)
    {
        pdfFileName = getFileName(uri);
        pdfView.fromUri(uri)
                .defaultPage(mCurrentPage)
                .onPageChange(this)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
                .onLoad(this)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .load();
    }
    @OnActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE)
    public void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            uri = intent.getData();
            displayFromUri(uri);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount)
    {
        mCurrentPage = page;
        setTitle(String.format("%s %s / %s", "Page Number", page + 1, pageCount));
    }
    public String getFileName(Uri uri)
    {
        String result = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content"))
        {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            try
            {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cursor != null)
                {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        }
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public void loadComplete(int nbPages)
    {
        if (mCurrentPage >= 0)
        {
            pdfView.jumpTo(mCurrentPage);
        }
        PdfDocument.Meta meta = pdfView.getDocumentMeta();
        Log.e(TAG, "title = " + meta.getTitle());
        Log.e(TAG, "author = " + meta.getAuthor());
        Log.e(TAG, "subject = " + meta.getSubject());
        Log.e(TAG, "keywords = " + meta.getKeywords());
        Log.e(TAG, "creator = " + meta.getCreator());
        Log.e(TAG, "producer = " + meta.getProducer());
        Log.e(TAG, "creationDate = " + meta.getCreationDate());
        Log.e(TAG, "modDate = " + meta.getModDate());
        Log.d(TAG, "totalPages " + nbPages);
        printBookmarksTree(pdfView.getTableOfContents(), "-");
    }
    public void printBookmarksTree(List<PdfDocument.Bookmark> tree, String sep)
    {
        for (PdfDocument.Bookmark b : tree)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("%s %s, p %d", sep, b.getTitle(), b.getPageIdx()));
            if (b.hasChildren())
            {
                printBookmarksTree(b.getChildren(), sep + "-");
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE)
        {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                launchPicker();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            mCurrentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_CURRENT_PAGE);
        }
        else
        {
            mCurrentPage = -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mCurrentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_CURRENT_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(KEY_CURRENT_PAGE, mCurrentPage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change orientation Android will by default reload the activity and this is why you are losing the current page.

There are 2 solutions one is the best practice and the other might work depending on the case.

Solution 1:

Save the last known page on `onSaveInstanceState` and then get the page back on `onCreate`

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putInt("current_page", pageNumber);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (savedInstanceState != null){
    pageNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_page");
  }
}
```

Solution 2:

Set the `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` atribbute in your Manifest file. This will retain the state of the screen exactly like it was before the orientation change.

Also please have a read on the activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` works fine but it could not `pdfView.fitToWidth();` If possible please put this method on above code it'll easy implement for me.

Comment: @AhmerAfzal you should go for solution 1 or add a onOrientationChange event and call pdfView.fitToWidth() when the orientation changes.