# Fullscreen mode on screen orientation change in jiaozi video player library

Tags: android

I am using **jiaozi video player** library for playing video in my android app. Everything is working fine. Now i am facing an issue, on screen orientation change from portrait to landscape the video should be fullscreen, has anyone done this, if yes then pls share me the code or snippet so that i can implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

Examplifying the code I got from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5726776/2232127

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        yourVideoPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        yourVideoPlayer.setFullscreen(false);
    }
}
```

I don't actually know your video player library, so the setFullscreen method probably doesn't exist. Try to find the equivalent for that.